# How much should I pay to Microsoft when I am selling a desktop & Web base software built on VB.NET using MS SQL 2005 Express Edition?

Tags: licensing

Can I distribute the MS SQL 2005 Express edition along with my application to the customer?

Comment: It's free to redistribute the express edition off SQL Server with your application.

Comment: @birryree - But you need to register for doing so first.

Answer (score 6):

> Can i distribute the MS SQL 2005 Express edition

You need to register for the free redistribution rights in order to do so. The contact details are [here](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/default.aspx). Not doing so may mean you are doing something illegal.

From the [SQL Server 2005 express download page](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=21844):

> Building and shipping applications with SQL Server Express? Sign up for [free redistribution rights here.](http://www.microsoft.com/sql/editions/express/redistregister.mspx)

You don't have to pay Microsoft when you sell software created using their tools. You may have to pay if you wish to redistribute the tools.